# Setting up a common class

Tags: java, android, sdk, countdowntimer

I have four classses in my application which have the same methods. Basically the code displays a CountDownTimer and plays music with the start of the timer.The music stops when the timer runs out. All four activities have the same layout file. The code is below:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Vyala extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
private static final int MILLIS_PER_SECOND = 1000;
private static final int SECONDS_TO_COUNTDOWN = 1;
TextView Time;
int totalTimeText;
MediaPlayer mp;
Button startTimer, howTo;
MediaPlayer bck;
protected CountDownTimer PushUpTimer;
protected int speed;
int PracticeCount;
AudioManager am;
SeekBar sb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.abhyasa);
    getRefs();
    setTotalTime();
    startTimer.setOnClickListener(this);

}

private void getRefs() {

    Time=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTime);

    startTimer=(Button) findViewById (R.id.bStart);
    howTo=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bHowTo);
    howTo.setOnClickListener(this);
    am=(AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound2);
    sb.setMax(am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
    sb.setProgress(am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
    sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
        {
//change the volume, displaying a toast message containing the current volume and    playing a feedback sound
      am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,progress, 0);
        }
  });
}

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
      {
  //if one of the volume keys were pressed
         if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN || keyCode ==   KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)
  {
        //change the seek bar progress indicator position  
             sb.setProgress(am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
  }
  //propagate the key event
  return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }




   private void getTheCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    int c=prefs.getInt("practicecount", 5);
    PracticeCount=c;


    }


private void getSpeed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SharedPreferences     getPref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    String values=getPref.getString("list","3");
    if(values.contentEquals("1")){
        speed=1;
    }else if(values.contentEquals("5")){
        speed=5;
    }else{
        speed=3;
    }   
}

private void setTotalTime() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    getSpeed();
    getTheCount();
    totalTimeText=PracticeCount*speed;
    Time.setText(String.format("%02d",  totalTimeText / 60) + ":" +     String.format("%02d",  totalTimeText % 60));
}

    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(v==startTimer){
        try {
              showTimer(PracticeCount*speed*SECONDS_TO_COUNTDOWN * MILLIS_PER_SECOND);

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
              // method ignores invalid (non-integer) input and waits
              // for something it cant use
            }
        }
        }   
    private void showTimer(int countdownMillis) {
          if(PushUpTimer != null) { PushUpTimer.cancel(); }
          PushUpTimer = new CountDownTimer(countdownMillis, MILLIS_PER_SECOND) {
          @Override
          public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
              mp.start();
              long seconds = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
              Time.setText(String.format("%02d", seconds / 60) + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds % 60));

          }
          @Override
            public void onFinish() {
              Time.setText("KABOOM!");
              mp.release();
            }
          }.start();
        }   
}
```

And this is the layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTime"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:text="@string/starttime"
    android:textSize="60sp" />

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/tvTime"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bStart"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tvTime"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bPause"
    android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:text="Start" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bPause"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/bStart"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bStart"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bHowTo"
    android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
    android:text="Pause" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/count"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/bHowTo"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
android:text="25"
android:textSize="80sp" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/bHowTo"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/count"
android:text="How" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

How do i set up a common class that all four activities can implement? Since it saves space and is a better way to code. I read that creating a fragment is a good solution, but i couldn't really understand the documentation provided by the android developer website.
If you can provide guidance on the coding with samples it would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why you have 4 classes that do the same thing. What is the difference between them? Figure that out first and explain it here.

Comment: The four classes show the time for different exercises. And each have a different textView to display on HowTo button click. The difference between the classes are the textView that they display. Eg say it is Activity1. It will launch an activity that displays details about Activity1. And Activity2 will display details about Activity2. And so on.

Comment: When you launch the activity you can specify extra data indicating which exercise to show in the textview. You can use getIntent to pull that data in you activity.

Answer (score 0):

This should work and is what you want according to my understanding.

```
public class redundant {

private Context _context;

    public redundant(Context context){
        this._context = context;
    }

     private void showTimer(int countdownMillis,MediaPlayer m,TextView v) {
              if(PushUpTimer != null) { PushUpTimer.cancel(); }
              PushUpTimer = new CountDownTimer(countdownMillis, MILLIS_PER_SECOND) {
              @Override
              public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                  m.start();
                  long seconds = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
                  Time.setText(String.format("%02d", seconds / 60) + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds % 60));

              }
              @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                  v.setText("KABOOM!");
                  m.release();
                }
              }.start();
            } 
}
```

use it in activity as:

```
Redundant r = new Redundant(activity.this);
r.showTimer(2000,mediaplayerobject,textview)
```